# Planner - error when creating a Task using Graph API

Tags: graph, microsoft-graph-api

Please advice:

Using the graph API http://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/docs/api-reference/beta/api/user_post_tasks I am getting the an error when I am creating a task.

Request URL: https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me/tasks

```
Request body:
{
"assignedTo":"9932ccb4-cb4c-412c-ada1-31dcded3ad5c",
"planId":"w8mzN1ED3EGDWqSw5l7LP5YACb5M",
"bucketId":"mpPMeTdosUGTsPnq2240gZYAF_L9",
"title":"Task1 form CRM",
"dueDateTime":"2016-03-31"
}

Error is:

{
  "error": {
    "code": "BadRequest",
    "message": "Write requests are only supported on contained entities",
    "innerError": {
      "request-id": "feb2d4ab-295e-42a3-a3f3-8115c837d9f5",
      "date": "2016-03-24T12:17:07"
    }
  }
}
```

What are we doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

As per [documentation](https://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/docs/api-reference/beta/api/task_post_tasks), the request should be "POST https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/tasks". Please retry and let me know the result.

Comment: Thank you, it worked. :-)  We are now able to create a task. Or next challenge is creating a Plan? We also have an issues with adding to groups when creating the plan.

Comment: We are now facing another problem. We get an error setting the StartDate.

`assignedTo
:
"9932ccb4-cb4c-412c-ada1-31dcded3ad5c"
bucketId
:
"7x-pjHnH0UWh5ot0XtCwYJYABnRQ"
dueDateTime
:
"2016-03-30"
planId
:
"w8mzN1ED3EGDWqSw5l7LP5YACb5M"
startDateTime
:
"2016-03-31"
title
:
"Test Task1"


The error we get:

{
  "error": {
    "code": "UnknownError",
    "message": "",
    "innerError": {
      "request-id": "c6114dd9-19f0-4795-8d1b-5c7a3d0ef853",
      "date": "2016-03-30T07:15:35"
    }
  }
}`

Comment: The failure is because startDateTime is later than dueDateTime. We will work on improving error message.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks this work for me, i followed the instruction from this documentation https://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/docs/api-reference/beta/api/user_post_tasks
why two page here i don't nm